# Property set to null when mapped value is added

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I created a piece of code that sets the property of a model to null when it is combined with another propert;

my model:

```
public partial class IngredientAmount
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string MealId { get; set; }
        public string IngredientId { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string DayId { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; } = new List<Ingredient>();

        public virtual Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
        public virtual Meal Meal { get; set; }
    }
```

My script that loads my model into a certain div by calling an url.action:

```
<script>
    function loadCreateIngredientAmountPartial() {
        $("#AddIngredient").load('@Url.Action("CreatePartial", "IngredientAmount", new IngredientAmount() { MealId = Model.Id, DayId = "2" })');
    }
</script>
```

My controller method:

```
 public ActionResult CreatePartial(IngredientAmount ingredient)
        {
            dbContext = new NutritionzContext();
            IngredientAmount ingredientAmount = new IngredientAmount() { MealId = ingredient.MealId, DayId = ingredient.DayId };
            ingredientAmount.Ingredients = dbContext.Ingredient.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
            return PartialView("~/Views/IngredientAmount/Create.cshtml", ingredientAmount);
        }
```

If I only send the DayId within the new IngredientAmount the property is filled, however when I add a mealId it turns empty.

Comment: ` {MealId = Model.Id, DayId = "2" }` is this value being populated: Model.Id?

Comment: Yes, its populated with the values i've sent from another view.

Comment: you are populating Model.Id not Model.MealId

Comment: That is because the model I use to populate the ingredient is the Meal model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way around my own question, the problem was that it wasn't routed correctly, so I created a new instance in the controller and just sent the two parameters via the action like so:

```
<script>
    function loadCreateIngredientAmountPartial() {
        $("#AddIngredient").load('@Url.Action("CreatePartial", "IngredientAmount", new { mealId = Model.Id, dayId = Model.DayId })');
    }
    </script>
```

Then I tasked the controller to route that specific action like so:

```
[Route("IngredientAmountController/CreatePartial/{mealId}/{dayId}")]
```